# Receive Floats using java sockets from C++

Tags: java, c++, sockets, inputstream

I need to receive an array or a class containing floats from a c++ client to java server using sockets. But the InputStreamReader is not getting it right. Any reasons.
Any suggestions for simpler ways would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

### Java Server Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
         Values values=new Values();
         gui display=new gui();
         display.setVisible(true);
        ServerSocket Sock=new ServerSocket(9090);
        try{
            while(true){
                System.out.println("Waiting");
                Socket socket=Sock.accept();

                    System.out.println("Connected..");
                  InputStream ins=socket.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader insr= new InputStreamReader(ins);
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(insr);

                    byte[]Array=br.readLine().getBytes("UTF-8");
                   // values.SetValues(Array);


                    values.tWidth=Array[0];
                    values.waterLevel=Array[4];
                    values.camHeight=Array[8];
                    values.camViewAngleY=Array[12];
                    values.camViewAngleX=Array[16];
                    values.distFromCamBank=Array[20];
                    values.distTwoPoints=Array[24];
                    values.AvgVelocity=Array[28];
                    values.crossSecArea=Array[32];
                    values.Flow=Array[36];
                    values.camTiltAngle=Array[40];
                    values.aboveWater=Array[44];
                    System.out.println(values.tWidth);
                    System.out.println(values.waterLevel);
                    display.SetValues(values);
                    socket.close();
                }

        }
        finally{
            Sock.close();
        }


    }
}
```

I am storing those float in a Class called Values. But the values I get are junk. I am checking the values in C++ code before sending and they seem fine. Dont know where its going wrong.
Please Help...!!

Comment: Perhaps you should read the comments I gave in your last question.  I am pretty sure that `IntVal` would be int not float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try

```
DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
byte[] bytes = new bytes[48];
ins.readFuly(bytes);
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

values.tWidth = bb.getFloat();
value.waterLevel = bb.getFloat();
// etc
```